# SP Online Modern List: Editing Enhanced Rich Text: Anyone else has this error?

Tags: sharepoint-online, custom-list, modern-experience, rich-text, multiple-lines-of-text

This is killing our customers and colleagues and I couldn't find information about this issue. I don't want to live on this planet anymore, if that is just the current state of the product.

- List with "Multiple Lines of Text - Enhanced Rich Text" field
- Create Item - everything fine
- Edit item
- Click somewhere on the rich text (for example to mark it)
- Click on "See more"

https://i.stack.imgur.com/zsRM0.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could reproduce your issue per my test that it seems that "See More" link doesn't work properly.

Given the situation, I suggest you post the requirement via [uservoice](https://sharepoint.uservoice.com/forums/329214-sites-and-collaboration)

If this issue is essential to your SharePoint environment, I suggest you open a ticket with Microsoft.

Similar issue:

https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sharepoint/multiple-lines-of-text-list-column-show-more-less-option-not/m-p/1160930

Comment: Thank you! I wasn't aware of uservoice. Also it seems that the issue got resolved in that linked thread over there. I will keep you updated.